# How to commit <style> tag into Alfresco node?

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to write a HTML content into Alfresco node using this service https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-services-content.html
but this service cut out "style", "script" and some other tags!!! how to prevent it and write "style" tag in output stream?

```
protected void exportReportVHTML(NodeRef reportNodeRef,
                            String outputFormat, String report) throws JRException, IOException {
    ContentWriter contentWriter = alfrescoServices.getContentServiceDefault().getWriter(reportNodeRef,
            ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
    OutputStream reportOS = contentWriter.getContentOutputStream();

    contentWriter.setMimetype(alfrescoServices.getMimetypeService().getMimetype("html"));
    try {
        reportOS.write(report.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception jrex) {
        jrex.printStackTrace();
        jrex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(reportOS));
        propertyHelper.setNodeProp(reportNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION, jrex.getMessage());
        throw jrex;
    } finally {
        reportOS.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The contentwriter shouldn't be stripping out tags.

If you download the html from the node, the tags should be retained.  Perhaps they are being removed in a "view in browser" or editor view (as tags deemed unsafe are typically removed).

See how to whitelist tags [here](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-blog/configuring-the-share-html-processing-black-white-list/ba-p/287343)